# Sort application windows side by side in alphabetical order

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a bat that launches 35 simultaneous screen sharing connections.  Right now, I right click the task bar and "Show windows side by side," but the order is kinda random.  I'm wondering if there's a programmatic approach to resizing and sorting the display, either from command line, python, C# or C++, java, or whatever language may work best, I'm not picky about the environment.  The computer is running windows 7, if that's relevant information. Anyone know of any API's or things that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

- pywinauto ( http://pywinauto.github.io/ )  - the simplest, but powerful
- autoit   ( https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ ) - it's a'la Visual Basic scripts, a lot of options
- robotframework ( https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/ )

source: https://github.com/atinfo/awesome-test-automation

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the links!  I'll start playing around with these and see where I end up.  If it goes well, I'll post some code here for others to reference

Answer (score 2):

Alright everyone, I used pywinauto, and after digging around, I figured it out.  This isn't a perfect template for everyone, but I'll explain my thought process and some snippets.  I was trying every angle I could, fancy mergesorts and what have you, to order the windows.  But I overlooked one detail:  the order you need them in does not correspond at all to the order they are in graphically.  I suggest you sorts two arrays, one based on the order you want them in (IE by title or text or class) and one based on the order of all the positions.  Anyway, onto the code

Here's how to interact with the taskbar to set all the windows side by side:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import taskbar

explorer = pywinauto.application.Application.connect(path = "explorer.exe")
pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper(pywinauto.taskbar.TaskBarHandle()).RightClick()
explorer.PopupMenu.Menu().GetMenuPath("Show windows side by side")[0].Click()
```

Probably a way cleaner way of doing it, but this worked for me.

Next, collect the windows you care about:

```
initlist = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows()
```

This will just find all windows.  You can narrow down what you'd like, more in the documentation, but side by side isn't exclusive to begin with.

I make two lists at this point with different attributes, one is a list of arrays with the program handle and the program title, the other is a list of coordinates based on the current instanced window:

```
for i in range (0, len(initlist)):
    orderlist.append([initlist[i], pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper(initlist[i]).Texts(), pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper(initlist[i])])
    poslist.append(pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper(initlist[i]).Rectangle())
```

Now, the best way I found to present them graphically was to traverse columns before rows.  Some may disagree, but Windows won't always have perfect number of rows from what I've seen.  So, we need to sort our first list:

```
orderlist = sorted(orderlist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This sorts on the title index.  Then we sort our second list:

```
poslist = sorted(poslist, key=lambda x: x.top + (x.left * 10000))
```

Notice how I weighted x.left.  We don't actually have a 2d array or grid that we're sorting, so I weighted the left because anything in the next column is further down in the list.

Finally, we traverse the lists one more time to swap the windows around:

```
for x in range(0, len(orderlist)):
    orderlist[x][2].MoveWindow(poslist[x].left, poslist[x].top, poslist[x].width(), poslist[x].height())
```

This will set all the windows from orderlist's coordinates to the sorted coordinates of all windows we want.  As a bonus, for those uneven windows, it will resize them to keep it all visually the same as side by side.

Hope this is clear and helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem too and that was my solution (you may face problems if you use Python 3.9):

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import taskbar

explorer = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(path = "explorer.exe")
pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper(pywinauto.taskbar.TaskBarHandle()).right_click()
print(explorer.PopupMenu.menu().get_menu_path("Show windows side by side")[0].click_input())
```